# Eclipse executes all tags of cucumber instead of the one that i am choosing

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

This is my first post!!

Here is the deal, i am using eclipse and i run locally some test to debug my code, i have two repositories, one from US and another one for EU, i have no issues while running any script in US, but on EU it executes all tags no matter what tag i specific on the run configurations.
Here is an example of the issue:
(it actually executes all the tags, from 1 to 43 in a random order)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhwpJ.png)
And here is the run configurations:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZcnK.png)
I cannot bring so much info because of NDA.

Here is more information about the run configurations:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ci0td.png)

I tried deleting the repository and clone it again, i didn't try to reinstall eclipse because if the issue is not happening on the US repository i dont think its an eclipse issue.

Comment: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56026910/6505250), `cucumber.options` is a Java property, not an environment variable. Does setting it in the _JRE_ tab as VM argument as `-Dcucumber.options="--tags @TC047"` work?

Comment: Note that `cucumber.options` has been replaced with dedicated properties. See https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/cucumber-core#properties-environment-variables-system-options